# how to make html p tag uneditable

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

wow 129 results on this topic, none answers such a basic issue that apparently i am not figuring out either. First, i am using CKEditor and it's more complex than i actually understand, for there is a textarea id='CAD' but my text var CAD_info gets loaded into a div and body tag that CKEditor somehow adds. That code is here:

```
var CAD_info = CKEDITOR.instances.CAD.getData();
jQuery("#CAD").html(CAD_info);
```

So, I stuff text into var CAD_info, and the text gets added into the page just fine. Now I simply want to prepend this text by a "p" tag, preferably, [or span with a line break], with readonly attribute, to the main text var CAD_info, and then all to the page like this:

```
var cad_text = '<?php echo $CAD_Text; ?>';
var CAD_info = cad_text;
var CAD_info = "<p id='type3_psc' contenteditable='false'>Customized Verbiage</p>" + cad_text;
var CAD_info = CKEDITOR.instances.CAD.getData();
jQuery("#CAD").html(CAD_info);
```

When I do that, the text shows up, but it's always editable. I tried

```
readonly
contenteditable="false"
giving the p an name of "ne" and using this, document.all.ne.contentEditable='false'
giving p id of #type3_psc and using jQuery("#type3_psc").attr("readonly", "1");
also, jQuery("#type3_psc").attr("contenteditable", "0");
```

... and nothing seems to render the text uneditable. Users should be able to edit the verbiage below the boiler plate verbiage only.

Comment: Why not just show the boilerplate outside the editor? If you want it included with user content add it back when it is saved and remove it again on subsequent edits

Comment: i tried that, but the verbiage appears above the toolbar which looks out of place. good suggestion, though; but i'd really like it to be inside the text editor, first paragraph uneditable.

Comment: If you want to add text to ckeditor you should use `CKEDITOR.instances.CAD.setData(CAD_info);` and notice your second var CAD_info is overwritten on line 4 and contain only CKEditor content

Comment: thx, SAZ, sounds helpful but i get error "Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined". besides, i put verbiage in a string var, then CKEditor displays that var + the regular CAD_info, the first var being in a simple <p> tag. what i want to do now is use jQuery to make that p tag "contentEditable='false'". doing that in Chrome console makes that p-tag info readonly.

Comment: @dcparham this is mean, that you have problem with your CKEDITOR, either you using wrong name or it haven't be initialized. Check in console results for CKEDITOR.instances

Comment: looking in Chrome console i see no errors, and the Editor displays the text fine including the Toolbar. it is maddening that the <p> tag seems "unreachable". it feels like something fundamental is missing here. thx for your efforts, though! it just seems like such a simple task yet still such a mystery.

Comment: hi, SAZ, i answered this in another related post - i finally created a new ckeditor using the builder on their site, and added Placeholder. i used my old config.js which had only the tools on the bar that i wanted; so the Placeholder is not on the toolbar now either; yet the code that the Placeholder creates when you add a placeholder to the editor is like this: [[placeholder goes here]] - add the two left ['s and two right ]'s around some data and viola, a yellow-highlighted placeholder, read only. it is troubling that you can delete it, however. no clues how to avoid.